# how to change selected value of combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony, combobox

I make a combobox.

I get data from database and set the value of firstname to combobox selected but it is not working.  Here is my code:

```
 $('#invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_firstname').val('{{firstname}}');
```

and here is my selectbox html:

```
<select id="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_firstname" required="required" name="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype[firstname]">
    <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option>
    <option value="2">Ilyas</option>
    <option value="3">Arif</option>
    <option value="4">Ali</option>
    <option value="5">Arslan</option>
</select>
```

`{{firstname}}` value is Ali,how do I set Ali as selected?

Comment: You need to map Ali to `4` somehow, because `4` is the value of the option you want to select and not `Ali`. So either you have a mapping in Javascript like `{Ilyas:2, .........., Ali: 4}` or you'll have to loop over all the options to determine the right one

Comment: or how about mapping "value"'s to names, e.g. <option value="Ali">Ali</option>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set {{firstname}} value as 4, not Ali

Answer (score 2):

You need to select an option by it's "value", not text node. Have a look at this and let me know if it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/4jGZD/

```
$('#invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_firstname').val(4);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using without {{}}

```
$("#invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_firstname").val("2");
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always insert PHP CODE if possible and avoid using the Jquery

```
<select id="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype_firstname" required="required"      name="invoices_invoicesbundle_invoicestype[firstname]">
<option disabled="disabled">Please Choose</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected"><?php echo $variable1DEFAULT ?></option>
<option value="3"><?php echo $variable2 ?></option>
<option value="4"><?php echo $variable3 ?></option>
<option value="5"><?php echo $variable4 ?></option>
</select>
```

i'm guessing something like that should work in your HTML